I have a state machine in stepfunction. I need to get notified whether the state machine successfully completed or not with the help of sns.how to do?
I have a multiple start job run in Awa stepfunction state machine. I need to get notified about the status of state machine , whether it is completed successfully or not with the help of sns publish. How do I do it. How should i need to connect the sns to my state machine .
I tried to setup the sns topic and now confused to whether to use lambda or is there any other possibilities

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your best option here is to use the Execution Status Change events that Step Functions emits to EventBridge. You can read about them in the docs here. You can use the EventBridge console to walk through this creation.
Or via CloudFormation, it might look something like this.
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'

Resources:
  RuleSendStepFunctionsExecutionStatusToSns:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: send-execution-status-to-sns
      EventPattern: >-
        {"source":["aws.states"],"detail-type":["Step Functions Execution Status
        Change"],"detail":{"stateMachineArn":["arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:state-machine"]}}
      State: ENABLED
      EventBusName: default
      Targets:
        - Id: Id496e47bb-fd77-467e-bec2-602bac1083c2
          Arn:
            Fn::Sub: >-
              arn:${AWS::Partition}:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:notification-topic
Parameters: {}


For eg. If the execution in the step function is completed successfully, is there a way that is notified to my email or if it gets failed . ??
